# ReactJS invalid component type

Tags: reactjs

Looking at the ["Choosing the Type at Runtime" section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) in the ReactJS docs, it looks like the following code should work:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { test: <div>Test</div>};
  }

  render() {
    const Test = this.state.test;

    return <Test />;
  }
}
```

However, nothing is rendered, and in the console I see the following error:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `App`.
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work; please explain.

Note that the above test app was created using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates an *element* - a particular instance of a DOM node to be rendered to screen.

```
this.state = { test: <div>Test</div>};
```

This takes that element and tries to treat it as a *component* - a React function or class that knows how to render itself as an element.

```
const Test = this.state.test;
return <Test />;
```

To use an analogy from traditional OO, this would be analogous to taking a class *instance* and trying to use it as a *class*.

Something like this should work instead:

```
this.state = { test: <div>Test</div>};
// ...
return this.state.test;
```

For more information, see ["React Components, Elements, and Instances."](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html)